# SystemSpeechLanguage is null on Xbox One UWP App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, speech-recognition, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

I am trying to bring a UWP App to Xbox and I am having troubles in Dev Mode when I run the app on the Console. My app uses the built in speech recognition libraries using grammar files (Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer - I am not using MS Cognitive Services... yet).

When I try to initialize my SpeechRecognizer, it throws an exception due to the fact that Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer.systemSpeechLanguage is null.

According to this article, that occurs when a speech language is not installed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn653252

So, does that mean I'm out of luck on Xbox One? Can a language be installed? The Kinect obviously handles speech so not sure what I'm missing, or what MS does not allow devs to use currently.

Answer (score 0):

The speech and language system for UWP is handled via Cortana which is not fully implemented yet for Xbox One - remember, it's only a preview so future updates may fix this.

The best advice I can give if you make sure your app works correctly on the desktop, phone, etc - but skip that code if the app is running on the Xbox.

Update: The [MSDN documentation now states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt693377.aspx) that the voice commands (ie. Cortana) are not supported at this time. I would expect support to be added nearer the final release (July/August 2016).

Comment: My app is entirely voice controlled, so it won't do much on the Xbox yet ;) I agree its early, so I'll probably have to wait for now.